# How to call webservice of .net from android

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I have created webservice .net, and I don't want to call it by URL, I want to create an object of webmethod and pass the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kSoap2 to call the webservice. Here is a good tutorial.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/CallWebServiceFromkSOAP.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you want to access your web service in a secured way like via soap protocol? if so you can use the library (link given below)

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Thanks